# Why is the following integral constant?

Tags: integration

Say $F(x)=\int^b_x f\,dt$ and $G(x)=\int^x_a f\,dt$, so $ F(x)=\int^b_a f\,dt-\int^x_a f\,dt $ where $x\in[a,b]$.

Why is the term $\int^b_a f\,dt$ constant, whereas the second term $\int_a^x f\,dt$ is not? I don't understand why this is true.

Comment: I believe in keeping simple things simple; hence my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following example: $f(x)=x, a=0, b=1.$ Then

$$\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx=\int_0^1 x\,dx=\left[\frac{x^2}2\right]_0^1=\frac 12.$$ That is, $\int_a^b f(x)dx$ is a constant, that dependns on $a,b$ and $f.$ But for given $a,b$ and $f$ is a constant.

However

$$\int_0^x f(t)\,dt=\int_0^x t\,dt=\left[\frac{t^2}2\right]_0^x=\frac{x^2}2$$ is a function of $x.$

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

You have that
$$-\int_a^b f(x)\,dx=\int_b^a f(x)\,dx$$
and by Chasles relation,
$$\int_a^b f(x)\,dx=\int_a^c f(x)\,dx+\int_c^bf(x)\,dx.$$

Comment: Yes I understand why this is true- but why is the term $\int_a^b fdt$ constant?

Comment: I'm sorry if this is a bad question, but I am genuinely confused about this

Comment: $\int_x^b f(t)dt$ is also constant. Notice that $F(x)$ is a fixed number.

Comment: that's what I was thinking- but what about $F'(x)$? It's not necessarily 0, right?

Comment: It is $F'(x)=-f(x),$ which is not zero unless $f\equiv 0.$

Comment: **@riri:** Of course that $F'(x)\neq 0$ but $(F(x))'=0$. Don't confuse $F'$ which is the derivate of $F$ and $(F(x))'$ which is the derivate of the function constant $y\mapsto F(x)$.

Comment: I'm sorry what's the difference between $F'(x)$ and $(F(x))'$? it seems to me they are both the derivative of $ F $ at the point $x$

Comment: Let $g(y)=F(x)$. $g'(y)=(F(x))'=0$ because $F(x)$ is not dépendant on $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Because "constant" in this context means "not depending on $x$", since $F(x)$ and $G(x)$ are functions of $x$.

Comment: thank you, I do too but a lot of times I have the tendency to make simple things complicated

Comment: especially with real-analysis. I think I was confused because the integral is with respect to $ t $ and not $x $